# using datatable after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to use my datatable after being called into another function but when I print it out, it indicates, that it's null meanwhile he call it, when he hasn't been created yet.

PS: I used drawCallback, initComplete same result.

```
var table= null;
  table =$('#example').dataTable( {
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            routage();
        }
    } );

function routage(){
 var a = getdataTable (); // getTable function call my datatable  or a= table;
console.log(a); // a is null can't use it later in my function 
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your `getdataTable` function? Are you initializing your jQuery DataTable within `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: We create global modul that contain many function to manipulate datatable globaly but even without `getdataTable` when i use static calls it print null and the table is there and load without problem. and i call the Datatable into a callback from another function
`$(document).ready()
function getTable(){
    return table;
}`

Comment: You can use the `api()` function to get a reference to the DataTable API object: `var table = $('#example').dataTable().api();`.  Does that get you what you need? There are actually 3 approaches - see the syntax [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/).